# Why doesn't my code increase a variable everytime?

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a code that loops through random numbers until it gets a six(this part is working) and then if you rolled a six in less than 6 tries but my code won't up my "amountOfMoney" variable if you get it in less than six. All it outputs is one even if you get under 6 two times in row. Here is the code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Start:

        int attempt = 0;
        int numberOfAttempts = 0;
        int amountOfMoney = 0;

        Random numberGen = new Random();

        while (attempt != 6)
        {
            attempt = numberGen.Next(1, 7);
            Console.WriteLine("Tom rolled: " + attempt + ".");
            numberOfAttempts++;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("It took tom " + numberOfAttempts + " attempts to roll a six");

        if(numberOfAttempts <= 6)
        {
            amountOfMoney++;
            Console.WriteLine("You now have " + amountOfMoney + " dollars");
        }

        if(numberOfAttempts > 6)
        {
            amountOfMoney--;
            Console.WriteLine("You now have " + amountOfMoney + " dollars");
        }

        Console.ReadKey();

        goto Start;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You should not be using `goto`, its a _very_ bad idea.  The reason you have this problem is because you used `goto`

Comment: Your goto start also resets the amountOfMoney to 0. So even though you get it twice, both increment from 0, and print 1

Comment: `goto` is indeed considered a bad habit.

Comment: Have a read of [Get started with Visual Studio 2017 - Debugging](https://tutorials.visualstudio.com/vs-get-started/debugging). Learning to debug effectively will greatly increase your independence as a developer.

Comment: There are times where `goto` is the better option, this is far far far from one of them. This is just bad programming and lazy thinking

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be using the tools available to you to solve this (i.e the *debugger*), but it seems like you are new so I will risk the downvotes in an attempt to help you...

The code you have is pretty close to what you need.  However the problem you have is a combination of using `goto`, and not understanding variable scope.

Let me be very clear: **goto is very bad practice**

When this line is hit:

```
goto Start;
```

It goes to the very top of your `Main()` method, the next 3 lines declare your variables and set them to `0`.  Thats why you are never able to persist the values.

You need to remove the `goto` and utilize a loop like you are *already* doing. Then put the variables you want to persist across loop iterations *outside the scope* of your new loop:

```
int amountOfMoney = 0;

while(someCondition)
{
    //game logic here
    amountOfMoney++;
}

//amountOfMoney has not reset every loop and now has all the changes you made to it
Console.WriteLine(amountOfMoney);
```

With your new loops you need to come up with an exit condition though.  Is it a user's input that exits the loop (and the game), is it a fixed number of loops (use a `for` loop).  That is up to you...

[I made a simple "coin-flip" game here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wvRNFV) so you can see an example of what I am talking about.  Doing the work for you wont help you learn but this should be more than enough to contextualize things for you.

Comment: although, `goto` is indeed a bad practice, the use of `goto` over use of a loop is not really related to OP's problem.  If the OP used the loop, in the same way he was using goto, he would be facing the same situation.

Comment: @SamIam good point, let me edit

Comment: "Very bad practice" -> Understatement of the year

Answer (score -1):

I'm answering because this is actually an awesome teachable moment. What you have provided is one of the simplest examples of a very common *design* issue, an uncontextualized neologism. This label:

```
Start:
```

...seems innocent enough. But in the programming world, things are actually very, very, specific, and this label is nowhere near specific enough. What exactly is starting?

Whoever wrote this code...

```
int attempt = 0;
int numberOfAttempts = 0;
int amountOfMoney = 0;
```

...thought it was the start of the game.

Whoever wrote this code...

```
goto Start;
```

...thought it was the start of the *round*.

To fix this, make the label more specific, and put it in the right place.

P.S. Also, don't use `goto` and come up with an exit condition. But I think those lessons are less valuable.

Comment: Is the downvote just because @JohnWu didnt condemn `goto` with all his might?

Comment: It's OK... people get very emotional about `goto`.